# Is Gradle 5 compatible with the Groovy @Field annotation?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I've been experiencing an issue with the `@Field` Groovy annotation isn't working when I upgrade from Gradle 4 to Gradle 5.

The error is:
`Cannot get the value of write-only property '<varname>' for script of type <typename>`

A very in depth description of the issue has been posted here:
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-5-0-field-variable-visibility-issue/

If there is a known issue please provide a link. Otherwise any ideas for how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find an answer to why this is happening. I did find a solution.

Replace `@Field` variables with the [ExtraPropertiesExtension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html).

Old:

```
@Field String outputJson = 'db.json'
```

New:

```
ext {
    outputJson = 'db.json'
}
```

Now you'll be able to refer to `outputJson` anywhere in the script just as you were able to on Gradle 4 with `@Field` annotation.